# Why this sql query is giving error which was previously working fine in C# ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, c#-4.0

I have `default.aspx` page in which I have placed `CreateUserWizard1`.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=.;database=test;integrated security=true");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
```

and, On `Continue_Click` event I have placed a code behind like this

```
protected void ContinueButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string un = CreateUserWizard1.UserName.ToString();
    try
    {
        con.Open();

        cmd.CommandText = "create table " + un + " (id int IDENTITY(1,1) primary key,username varchar(50),fname varchar(50),mname varchar(50),lname varchar(50),mobile varchar(10),college varchar(5000),school varchar(5000),working varchar(5000),prevworking varchar(5000),skill varchar(MAX),interest varchar(MAX),achievment varchar(MAX),image varchar(MAX) default '~/image/default_male.jpg')";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

     }

    Catch (Exception a)
    {
         Response.write(a.Message);
    }
 }
```

Which was previously working fine but now it’s giving error  and executing catch block stating

```
Incorrect syntax near '('.
```

Will you please help me to find the problem and give me solution?

Some Other details of machine.XML are

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>

<membership>
        <providers>
            <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
        </providers>
    </membership>
```

Comment: Offtopic, but why you're creating new table for new user? Usually only new record in existing table is created...

Comment: Also somewhat off-topic, you should [accept the answers to some of your previous questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

If your variable `un` is from an untrusted source, it's not a good idea to use it for building a command string. My first guess might be, that the value of that variable contains illegal characters for your sql-query?

I think you could import that value by using SqlCommand Parameters. Basically, you replace your dynamic string building by using an sqlparameter, which you then define for your command:

CommandString:

```
cmd.CommandText = "create table @TableName (id int IDENTITY(1,1) primary key,username varchar(50),fname varchar(50),mname varchar(50),lname varchar(50),mobile varchar(10),college varchar(5000),school varchar(5000),working varchar(5000),prevworking varchar(5000),skill varchar(MAX),interest varchar(MAX),achievment varchar(MAX),image varchar(MAX) default '~/image/default_male.jpg')";
```

Importing Parameter (You need to do this before calling `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` ):

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TableName", un);
```

I hope this helps, pls let us know if it changes anything :)

Comment: My bad, object names cannot be supplied via sql-parameters. sorry!

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/ff5939e0-220a-4057-8fcb-96174477896f/

Comment: After Continue_Click() its not getting CreateUserWizard1.UserName.ToString() or HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name and now even login for existing users is also showing unsuccessfull. Why is that?